# How to prevent from cutting string field values in a crystal Reports8.5 report?

Tags: string, crystal-reports, field

There is an old application written with VB6 and Crystal Reports 8.5.

One of the reports (for example "report1") has used active data method for retrieving data from SQL Server. It contains a field named "Description" that has 500 characters at most.
The problem is that the field ("Decription") is cut down to 256 characters.

How can I prevent it in order to show all?

Comment: Is it always truncating the field to 250 characters, or only on export to Excel? Was the description field previously 250 characters, and has it recently been expanded to 500 characters? Have you tried seeing whether using different database drivers with Crystal (eg. Native versus ODBC) produces the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a formula field, I believe a formula field in Crystal Reports 8.5 can only hold up to 256 characters.  I can't imagine *why* Crystal Reports does that, but there you have it.

Here's a link to a Crystal Reports Underground article on how to use multiple variables and a text object to display the full contents of the text:    http://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/130